# Why does adding parentheses produce a different result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've come across a weirdness in Python I don't understand:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> L = [1, 2]
>>> u = True
```

```
>>> x in L == u
False
>>> (x in L) == u
True
>>> x in (L == u)
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable.
```

Can someone explain how Python processes `x in L == u` and `(x in l) == u`?

Thank you.

Python version: 3.9.12

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) knows all.

Comment: Okay, a link on Operator Precedence tells all....

Comment: also, in this case, `in` and `==` are both comparison operators (which is a bit counterintuitive to me that `in` is) [so they are chained](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), and `x in L == u` is the same as `x in L and L == u`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` and `==` have the same precedence, but looking at the python language [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) section, these operations are chained so that an expression such as `a < b < c` work in the mathematical sense, unlike languages such as C.

> Formally, if a, b, c, …, y, z are expressions and op1, op2, …, opN are comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent to a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

Thus `x in L == u` is equivalent to `x in L and L == u`. Python does not use the result of `x in L` in the next comparison. In fact, if `x` is not in `L`, python would short-circuit immediately and would not even execute the `==` comparison.

When you group with parenthesis, these operations are no longer chained. `x in L` is evaluated as an expression and its result is used in the next comparison.